# Trying to identify a design pattern

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns

I am currently working with an inherited piece of code that uses a very interesting design pattern.

The code is split into a number of objects.  I am not sure if the term object is applicable since it is a C code, but it is the best analogy.  Each object has object-specific data, a thread, and a message queue.  All objects primarily communicate by placing pre-defined messages onto each-other's queues. The main idea seems to be is that each object's data is only accessed by one thread.  After doing some research I discovered that a few industrial automation applications are written this way (namely the ProfiNET stack and some EIP implementations).

Do you know if this pattern has a name or if it is describes somewhere in the literature?  The "Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture" book by Schidt, Stal, et al does not mention it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds somewhat related to the [Actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model).

Answer (score 0):

It might be me but is  any other pattern except producer consumer combined with mutual exclusion used in what you described ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes#Informal_description)

> CSP allows the description of systems in terms of component processes
>   that operate independently, and interact with each other solely
>   through message-passing communication

It is actually one of the core design concepts that the [Go language](http://golang.org/) is based upon for [communicating between goroutines](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#csp) (concurrency).